# Replace all <link> tags containing given href attribute with Regex or DOM

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, pattern-matching

I'm struggling with this. The idea is to replace all `<link>` tags, containing specific `href` attribute inside given string (which comes from a buffer and it is regular HTML, but malformed sometimes).

I've tried to use the PHP `DOM` approach, also the [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) parser library, so far nothing works for me (the problem is that `DOM` approach returns only links inside `<body>` element, but not those in `<head>` section of the page), so I decided to use regex.
Here is the non-working PHP `DOM` approach code:

```
function remove_css_links($string = "", $css_files = array()) {
        $css_files = array("http://www.example.com/css/css.css?ver=2.70","style.css?ver=3.8.1");
            $xml = new DOMDocument();
        $xml->loadHTML($string);
        $link_list = $xml->getElementsByTagName('link');
        $link_list_length = $link_list->length;
        //The cycle
            for ($i = 0; $i < $link_list_length; $i++) {
          $attributes = $link_list->item($i)->attributes;
          $href = $attributes->getNamedItem('href');
          if (in_array($href->value, $css_files))  {
            //Remove the HTML node
          }                 
        }
        $string = $xml->saveHTML();
        return $string;
}
```

Here is the regex code, however I know that all of you do not recommend to use it for parsing of HTML, but let's not discuss this here and now:

```
$html_text = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Website &raquo; Feed" href="/feed/" />
<link rel=\'stylesheet\'  href=\'http://www.example.com/css/css.css?ver=2.70\' type=\'text/css\' media=\'all\' /></head>
<body>...some content...
<link rel=\'stylesheet\' id=\'css\'  href=\'style.css?ver=3.8.1\' type=\'text/css\' media=\'all\' />
</body></html>
';
$url = preg_quote("http://www.example.com/css/css.css?ver=2.70");
$pattern = "~<link([^>]+) href=".$url."/?>~";
$link = preg_replace($pattern, "", $html_text);
```

The problem with the regex is that the `href` attribute can be at any place inside `<link>` tag and this one, which I use, can detect any type of `<link>` tags, as you can see I do not want to remove the `shortcut icon` or `alternate` types of them, as well as anything different than given URL as `href` attribute. You can notice that the `<link>` tags contains different type of quotes, single and/or double.

However, I'm open to suggestions and if it is possible to make the `DOM` approach work, rather than use regex - it's OK.

Comment: Hate to be one of the mass - but experience shows that, as much as I love it, when it comes to HTML parsing, RegEx is *not* the tool for the job. Please, have a look at my reply below... :-)

Comment: Currently testing it...;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OK, so here you are :**

```
<?php

$html_text = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Website &raquo; Feed" href="/feed/" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://www.example.com/css/css.css?ver=2.70" type="text/css" media="all" /></head>
<body>...some content...
<link rel="stylesheet" id="css"  href="style.css?ver=3.8.1" type="text/css" media="all" />
</body></html>
';

$d = new DOMDocument();
@$d->loadHTML($html_text);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$result = $xpath->query("//link");

foreach ($result as $link)
{
    $href = $link->getattribute("href");

    if ($href=="whatyouwanttofilter")
    {
          $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
    }

}

$output= $d->saveHTML();
echo $output;

?>
```

Tested and working. Have fun! :-)

---

**The general idea is :**

- Load your HTML into a `DOMDocument`
- Look for `link` nodes, using `XPath`
- Loop through the nodes
- Depending on the node's `href` attribute, delete the node (actually, remove the child from its... parent - well, yep, that's the php way... lol)
- After doing all the cleaning-up, re-save the HTML and get it back into a string